# WPF application changing size

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

So, it is my first time working with a wpf application in VS 2012 for windows desktop. 
I put some background image in to a window. I put three text boxes and a button on to that window. Now I have a problem, when I start the application and I change the size of a window with mouse or go fullscreen, the window changes its size, but textboxes and button stay at the same position as before, and they do not really fit into that design. I hope I was clear enough. Thank you for your help.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1366
    ">

<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.495,0.498" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="slike/education_board.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="209" Margin="209,211,0,0"        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="396">

    <TextBox x:Name="tockeMaturaTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="120" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Margin="10,0,0,176"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tretjiLetnikTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.899,3.574" Margin="10,63,0,0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="cetrtiLetnikTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="361,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="skupneTockeTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,133,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"      RenderTransformOrigin="-0.375,0.338" Height="73" Width="113"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: If you remove the margin properties from your textboxes, they will be free to change position as needed.  Put them inside a StackPanel and they will then be automatically stacked vertically.

Comment: you should try Expression Blend with you app. it makes it easy to dock controls with the grid and thus it will easily adjust with windows size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the XAML below a try:

```
    <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="211"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="slike/education_board.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >

            <TextBox x:Name="tockeMaturaTextBox" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="120" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1" IsManipulationEnabled="True" />
            <TextBox x:Name="tretjiLetnikTextBox" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
            <TextBox x:Name="cetrtiLetnikTextBox" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="button" Margin="5" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="skupneTockeTextBlock" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"       Height="73" Width="113"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

WPF uses a container-based (relative) layout system.  You were placing your textboxes in absolute positions by defining their margins precisely with respect to the parent grid.  In the example above, they are placed in a `StackPanel` which is inside the grid.

With all the extra margins and absolute widths and heights, it's hard to tell what final result you are going for, but the XMAL above should get you close.  You can change the relative sizes of the grid rows and columns to get what you need; or completely redefine the structure of the `Grid`.

I think a good tutorial on WPF is in order to get a handle on the basic conocepts:
[Silverlight/WPF Introduction](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DEV209). This is geared a little bit towards Silverlight, but the layout principles are identical to WPF.  Actual training starts at 8:17 in the video.

**EDIT**
For magical expanding and shrinking content, use the code below:

```
    <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="slike/education_board.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox x:Name="tockeMaturaTextBox" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="120" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1" IsManipulationEnabled="True" />
                <TextBox x:Name="tretjiLetnikTextBox" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
                <TextBox x:Name="cetrtiLetnikTextBox" Margin="0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Button x:Name="button" Margin="5" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="skupneTockeTextBlock" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"       Height="73" Width="113"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: thanks, that works fine. I'm also trying to achieve, that, when I would move, or I should say resize this form, that those textboxes would resize either, or move along with the background picture, but they dont..

Comment: i dont know if you understand me, i really dont know how to explain, i want my apllication look the same in fullscreen and in windowed.. only in windows it's all smaller..

Comment: Oh, that's easy then.  Just put everything in a Viewbox.  See edit.

Comment: @user2090925, You're welcome.  Click the checkmark next to the answer so then other people know that this was a helpful solution.